# How to load previously downloaded pdf from cache or external storage

Tags: pdf, caching, picasso, download, android-external-storage

```
public class physics extends AppCompatActivity {
PDFView pdfViewph;
ImageView image;

ProgressBar progressbar;


    TextView ans4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans4);

    // Set a click listener on that View
    ans4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        category is clicked on.
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            new RetrievePDFBytes().execute("https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B7aQiU7nV3LranpkTi1FZ2hOZmc&export=download");
        }
    });}
class RetrievePDFBytes  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,byte[]> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    progressbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);
    progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected byte[] doInBackground(String... strings) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200)
            {
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(byte[] bytes) {
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);;
         pdfViewph.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         pdfViewph.fromBytes(bytes).load();






    }
}
}
```

`I am trying to build an app that have a buttons each  download a book but what I want is to on clicking the button it download a book only the first time. Then if the user clicked again after a time to complete reading it, load it from a file or cache instead of re-downloading all again.

Comment: Please add the example code you're having the issue with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the button is clicked, run a function to check if the file exists first, something like this:

```
public boolean fileExists(String filename){
    File f= getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(filename);
    return f.exists();
}
```

If the function returns true, then you know that the user has downloaded that file before. Just use that file instead of running the download.